# Let telegram bot react while a document is sent to a group chat

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want my bot to send a message when it detect documents is sent in a chat.
I add a message handler with document filter.
The code works for chat to the bot directly,
but if I add the bot into a group,
the bot has no response if I sent a document in the group.

The code is:

```py
def test(bot, update):
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, text='OK!')
    print "OK"

def main():
    token = 'xxxxxxyyyyy'
    updater = Updater(token, workers=10)

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler([Filters.document], test))

    updater.start_polling(timeout=10)
    updater.idle()
```

Why the bot has no response when I send a file in a group?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If code is working in private chat but not working( not receiving messages sent) in a group , the reason is you do NOT set `/setprivacy` in `BotFather`.

> Go to `BotFather` and disable `/setprivacy` for your bot. In this
>   state, your bot will receive all messages not just does start with
>   slash(/) in GROUPS.